# Running multiple web crawlers at the same time in Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, web-crawler, python-multithreading

I created a custom management command for Django called crawl.py

I would like to make it run two crawlers at the same time.
my crawlers are each an object with a crawl() function that runs an infinite loop and interacts with the orm.

```
def crawl(self):
    current_page = self.start_page
    while True:
        page_response = requests.get('http://magdeleine.co/browse/page/{}/'.format(current_page))
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.text)
        image_links = [link["href"] for link in page_soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'photo-link'})]


        for image_link in image_links:
            response = requests.get(image_link)
            image_page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
            print('getting image source link')
            image_source_link = image_page_soup.find('a',{'class': 'download'})['href']

            #Get Tags
            print('getting tags')
            ul = image_page_soup.find('ul', {'class': 'tags'})
            tag_links = ul.find_all('a', {'rel':'tag'})
            tag_names = [tag_link.string for tag_link in tag_links]
            try:
                tag_names.remove('editor\'s pick')
            except:
                pass

            if not Image.objects.filter(url=image_source_link).exists():
                image = Image(url=image_source_link, origin="MG")
                print('creating thumbnail')
                image.create_thumb()
                image.save()
                # get or create a new tag for every element in the list
                for tag_name in tag_names:
                    tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
                    image.tags.add(tag)

        current_page+=1
        print("end page")
```

in my management command

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        pexel_crawler = PexelCrawler()
        pexel_crawler.crawl()

        magdeleine_crawler = MagdeleineCrawler()
        magdeleine_crawler.crawl()
```

I would like to run both .crawl() commands together.
Also if someone could elaborate how this is done in production vs development and optimal solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with gevent, something like:

```
import gevent
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        pexel_crawler = PexelCrawler()
        magdeleine_crawler = MagdeleineCrawler()
        pexel_job = gevent.spawn(pexel_crawler.crawl)
        magdeleine_job = gevent.spawn(magdeleine_crawler.crawl)
        gevent.joinall([pexel_job, magdeleine_job])
```

I believe that will work, and keep the management command running in the foreground for as long as both crawlers are running. I would be careful though, because if this works as expected, it will truly be an infinite loop and never stop.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for that task.
Crawl operation can take many time and if we invoke it from cmd it's ok we control task but on production you will call it from cron/view/etc so better to have control over 
task life cycle.

Install Celery and Django management tool [djcelery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery/)

```
pip install celery
pip install djcelery
```

For message broker i suggest to install RabbitMQ

```
apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

in settings.py of your Django project add

```
import djcelery

djcelery.setup_loader()

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler' #To make crawl call by shedule.
```

Create file tasks.py in your project and put this code.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.management import call_command
@shared_task
def run_task():
    print call_command('your_management_command', verbosity=3, interactive=False)
```

To control your task install [flower](https://github.com/mher/flower).

```
apt-get install flower
```

Run your task at first:

Run rabbitmq server

```
service rabbitmq-server start
```

Then run celery

```
service celeryd start
```

And then flower to control execution of your tasks.

```
service flower start
```

That's it you can now run your crawler tasks and you would have any troubles with this.

Comment: so I need to separate each crawler into a different management command to run them together?

Comment: With separated management commands you can control execution and stop if job will take much memory/cpu/etc. You can restart job if they don't answer.

Comment: Ok and what happens if both tasks try adding to the database at the same time?

Comment: Well it doesn't matter in same time or not. In most cases all insert operations added in queue. So images will save in database. Don't worry about order. You can even make distributed crawler run tasks in many nodes and store all in single database.